# MVC Render JSONResult as a Literal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, autocomplete

I have a JsonResult action in my MVC project...

```
public JsonResult GetData(string term) {
    List<String> data = repo.GetData(term).ToList();
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This powers a jquery autocomplete lookup but as there is only 30 values in the database, I think that this is not efficent use of database resources...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("input#MyTextBox").autocomplete({
            source: '<%: Url.Action("GetDate","Controller") %>',
                delay: 1,
                minChars: 2
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

I would like to generate something simlar to this...

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input#MyTextBox").autocomplete({
    source: ["my","list","of","values"]
});
  });
</script>
```

I am missing something here as this should be simple. Is there a way that I can change the url.action to something that will render the JSON almost like a PartialView ?

Also, is this a good solution to the problem or can someone show me a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 points:

1. Yes, there is a way to render JSON easier:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
       $("input#MyTextBox").autocomplete({
           source: <%: Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.AutocompleteSourceFromDb)) %>,
               delay: 1,
               minChars: 2
           }
       );
   });
   </script>
   ```
2. From database usage perspective this doesn't change a thing. You still rendering the whole JSON on page render and not querying database on autocomplete.